# djangocms_text_ckeditor not working on Google chrome

Tags: python, django, django-cms, djangocms-text-ckeditor

I have install Django Cms by hand using this tutorial http://docs.django-cms.org/en/release-3.4.x/how_to/install.html.

However, for some reason I can't add or edit text when using Google Chrome. On Firefox and Safari I can do it.

[image]

[console JS errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GAElA.png)

Comment: What's in the console, any JS errors?

Comment: yes: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'label' of undefined

Comment: @Browing and that is coming from CKeditor, so if you fix that the editor will no doubt load.

Comment: @markwalker_ how can i fix that? its working fine on firefox